# Error 20728-F while in using Crystal Reports in VB6

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Reports in my VB6 project, but I'm facing error while loading the report in `crystalreport1.action=1`; Please give me some solution for this problem. It is showing the error as `Error in 20728-F`

```
cryStockReport.ReportTitle = "Total Stock Report"
cryStockReport.SQLQuery = "select * from Tr_stockcenter,ma_product where sc_productcode=pr_productcode and sc_yearcode=" & intyearcode & " order by sc_Productcode"
cryStockReport.ReportFileName = App.Path & "\stock.rpt "
cryStockReport.WindowTitle = "STOCK REPORT"
cryStockReport.WindowState = crptMaximized
cryStockReport.DiscardSavedData = True
cryStockReport.Action = 1
```

Comment: What exact error message you get? What version of Crystal Reports (and what kind of its component - ActiveX viever, RDC component or whatever else) you're using?

Comment: i am using cryst32.ocx dll,version is Crystal Reports v10.0.0.533 Professional Edition,control is crystalreport, and i am getting error as 20728-f

Answer (score 4):

A quick search on 'crystal report error 20728-F' led me to this [thread](http://www.dbforums.com/crystal-reports/1619106-problem-crystal-reports-8-5-11-a.html).  It appears that you may be missing cpre23.dll and dwmapi.dll.

Comment: Is this still valid for windows 10. I'm facing the same issue but not able to register crpe32.dll