# Getting error 20507 while launching Crystal Report 8 using VB6

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports-8.5

I received an old source code from the client and now he wants me to analyze and make it work again. I resolved 90% of the issues, but when I try to launch the crystal report, it shows me an error with not much information.

I am using VB6 with Crystal Report 8

**This is the VB function where I am getting error**

```
Private Sub cmdPrint_Click()
Screen.MousePointer = vbArrowHourglass
    db.Execute ("Delete from TempReports")
    db.Execute ("Delete from TempReports1")
    With vsFlx
    For I = 1 To .Rows - 1
        db.Execute ("insert into TempReports (field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8, field19,field20,field14,field15,field16,field17,field18,field13,field21,field22)  values ('" & .TextMatrix(I, 0) & "','" & .TextMatrix(I, 1) & "','" & .TextMatrix(I, 2) & "','" & .TextMatrix(I, 3) & "','" & .TextMatrix(I, 4) & "','" & .TextMatrix(I, 5) & "','" & .TextMatrix(I, 6) & "','" & .TextMatrix(I, 7) & "','" & MaskStartDate.Text & "','" & MaskEndDate.Text & "','" & fixquotes(lblItemGroup.Caption) & "','" & fixquotes(lblSubGroup.Caption) & "','" & fixquotes(lblSubsubGroup.Caption) & "','" & fixquotes(lblItemName.Caption) & "','" & fixquotes(lblMainItemName.Caption) & "'," & Val(txtBalanceQty) & ",'" & lblTotQtyIn.Caption & "','" & lblTotQtyOut.Caption & "') ")
    Next
    End With
    
    With vsFlx2
    For I = 1 To .Rows - 1
        db.Execute ("insert into TempReports1 (field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8, field19,field20)  values ('" & .TextMatrix(I, 0) & "','" & .TextMatrix(I, 1) & "','" & .TextMatrix(I, 2) & "','" & .TextMatrix(I, 3) & "','" & .TextMatrix(I, 4) & "','" & .TextMatrix(I, 5) & "','" & .TextMatrix(I, 6) & "','" & .TextMatrix(I, 7) & "','" & MaskStartDate.Text & "','" & MaskEndDate.Text & "') ")
    Next
    End With
            crpt.ReportFileName = "reports\StockLedger.rpt"
            crpt.SQLQuery = "Select * from TempReports order by id"
            crpt.DiscardSavedData = True
            crpt.WindowShowPrintSetupBtn = True
            crpt.Action = 2
            crpt.Destination = crptToWindow
Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault
End Sub
```

**Getting error on this particular line**

> crpt.Action = 2

**Screenshots for reference**

[image]
[image]

any help is highly appreciated

**UPDATE 1**
I tried error handling and then I got following error message

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Tried to register crpe32.dll and dwmapi.dll as suggest by craig but getting these errors

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error 20728-F while in using Crystal Reports in VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728427/error-20728-f-while-in-using-crystal-reports-in-vb6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by reinstalling everything. I was running this project on Virtual Machine. So, reinstalling OS and everything fixed the issue.

I think I might messed up something by installing external dlls or replacing existing ones.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably missing some dlls.
Do you have cpre23.dll and dwmapi.dll ?

Comment: Yepp, [that seems to be it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728427/error-20728-f-while-in-using-crystal-reports-in-vb6)

Comment: I tried to register `cpre23.dll` and `dwmapi.dll` but failed with errors. I have updated my answer with these errors.

Comment: These are _not_ COM DLLs, but native Win32 DLLs and therefore **can't** be registered. They need to be present in [Window's search path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order) however.

Comment: I fixed this issue by reinstalling everything. I was running this project on VM. So, reinstalling OS and everything fixed this issue.